# PHP Script return special character in String using JQuery POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an issue in this code:

```
    var dataForm = $(this).serialize(), 
        _user = recognizeUser(this);

    $.post(_user, dataForm, function(data, textStatus){

        alert(data);
        if(data == "true") {
            alert("I'm in");
            location.href = URL;
        }

        return false;
    });
```

So, the PHP Script returns the right data but with a space before the "true" ("alert(data)" shows "true" like the image below).

[image: Incorrect text output]

The PHP code is:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $result = $result->fetch_assoc();


    $_SESSION['username'] = $result['Username'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $result['Password'];

    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "No user found";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: try replacing echo "true" by return true and replace data == "true" by data == true

Comment: `echo true` without quotes.

Comment: I disagree with both comments. If you want to output something to the client in a PHP script, you `echo` it. Also, http messages are strings, not booleans, so it doesn't even make sense to output a boolean, nor to check whether the output is equal to a particular boolean (`true`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is definitely in you PHP script, before the snippet you have posted (because its prepending the space/tab/whatever before the string `true`);

It might be a space before opening `<?php` tag.

If it is a whitespace character (e.g. spaces and tabs), 
you can overcome it simply by calling JS string method `trim()` which will strip all those whitespace characters (e.g. spaces and tabs) from beginning/end of the string:

```
data = data.trim();
if(data == "true") {
    alert("I'm in");
    location.href = URL;
}
```

Comment: Yes, OP should check what is being output before `<?php`. But it doesn't look like a whitespace character to me. In which case `data = data.trim();` won't help. As you said, the real answer is to change the PHP script so it doesn't send the character in the first place.

Comment: Well I didnt see the screenshot first, you are probably right. I adjusted the answer to be clear what is the problem and when will the `.trim` solution work.

Comment: Thank both of you for the answer! I just tryed the method .trim() and It works! I cheked the PHP Script and I didn't find a space at the beginning of the script... probably It is somewhere in the file. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Never mind... I found a space at the end of the PHP script. Thank you again!

Comment: It might be also BOM: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark#remove

Comment: I didn't know about BOM. Yes, that probably explains it. I still think there should be a way to prevent this from happening server-side, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: I suppose PHP isn't really meant for sending anything other than HTML pages. A browser would ignore (or handle correctly) a BOM at the start of a webpage.